# Change double integral to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have an integral $$ \int_{1}^{2} \int_{0}^{2 - y} f\left(x, y\right) \mathrm{d}x \: \mathrm{d}y$$ and I need to change into polar coordinates. The area looks like this:
[image]

Since there's no easy way of saying which bounds $r$ will have, we need to use a substitution into one of the following inequalities:

$$ 1 \leq y \leq 2, $$
$$ 0 \leq x \leq 2 - y. $$

By substituting into $x$ inequality I get:
$$ x \geq 0 \implies r \cdot \cos \varphi \geq 0 \implies r \geq 0 $$
$$ x \leq 2 - y \implies r \cdot \cos \varphi \leq 2 - r \cdot \sin \varphi \implies r \leq \frac{2}{\sin \varphi + \cos \varphi},$$
so the integral would look like this $$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sin \varphi + \cos \varphi}} f \left( r \cos \varphi, r \sin \varphi \right) \mathrm{d}r \: \mathrm{d}\varphi $$
But when doing the same for the $y$ inequality, the integral would be different:

$$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{\sin \varphi}}^{\frac{2}{\sin \varphi}} 
f \left( r \cos \varphi, r \sin \varphi \right) \mathrm{d}r \: \mathrm{d}\varphi $$

Which one is right and how to choose where to subtitute?

Comment: $r\cdot\cos\varphi\ge0 \Rightarrow \cos\varphi\ge 0$, since $r\ge0$ always.

Comment: Your first integral is close to the truth, though the limit of integration over r does not start from zero. Your nice picture could help you to see this - just draw polar coordinates on it (angle and r) and check the integration limits.

Comment: Actually, you need to combine bits and pieces of both. But, yes, look at the picture. Draw a ray of constant $\theta$ and see where it enters and where it exits.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks this works perfectly.

Comment: It should be $\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \leq r \leq \frac{2}{\sin \theta + \cos \theta}, \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.